# Verilog: Understanding multiple driver on bidirectional signal

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am debugging some Verilog code and I'm having some difficulty understanding a bidirectional signal with multiple drivers:

The verilog code looks like this:

```
inout a;

assign a = b ? c : 1'bz
       a=Stx b=St1  c=St0
assign (weak0, weak1) a = d ? 1'bz : (e ? 1'b0 : (f ? 1'b1 : 1'bz));
       a=Stx  d=St0 e=St0 f=St0
```

Signal `c` is the actual data that needs be transmitted to `a` (output pad). When I run the simulation using a commercial simulator, I get the values annotated above. I don't understand why `a` ends up being X throughout the simulation. `b` is toggling and `c` is also toggling. `d/e/f` are always 0. The 2nd statement is using a weak pull-up/pull-down but by setting it `d/e/f=0`, it should drive Z. So the other statement should `win` out?

Comment: There must be something else driving this port from the outside. I would create a simple test case with just these two assignments to see if your simulator can handle it.

Comment: You are correct. It was a multiple drivers issue resulting in X. At the top test-bench level the BFM was driving this signal when it is supposed to be receivign it as input! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code above, you are in essence creating a bidirectional buffer which is one input buffer from IO pad to internal signal, and an output buffer from internal signal to IO pad that is controlled by an **enable**. The b signal is the enable on one side and the d signal is the enable on the other side.

[image: bidirectional_buffers_sketch]

Remember that a bidirectional signal or bus must still have some kind of arbitration on it, something that understands the bidirectional transactions that are occurring as both sides should not be enabling their output buffers at the same time.